# how do I assign a value to a struct array inside a struct in c?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, variable-assignment

So I need to assign the scanned values to the variables `palo` and `valor` which belong to `cartas`which is a struct, and this one is inside another struct?

This is what I've got so far and i get an error "must have pointer-to-object type":

````c
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIM 100

typedef struct{
    char palo;
    int  valor;
}t_carta;

typedef struct{
    int ncartas;
    t_carta cartas[DIM];
}t_baraja;

int main(){
    t_baraja b1;
    t_carta carta[DIM][DIM];

    printf("Cuantas cartas tiene su baraja? ");
    scanf("%d", &b1.ncartas);
    printf("Introduzca las cartas separadas por guiones (o4-e10-b1...):\n");
    for(int i=0; i<b1.ncartas; i++){
        scanf("%c%d%*c", &b1.cartas->palo, &b1.cartas->valor);
        b1.cartas[i][i]=b1.cartas->valor;
    }

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: @martiwg The data member t_carta cartas[DIM]; is a one-dimensional array. So why are you using two indices b1.cartas[i][i]=b1.cartas->valor;? This statement does not make a sense.

Comment: @martiwg And what is this array  t_carta carta[DIM][DIM]; doing?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I don't know my teacher sent this as a header and didn't really understand how i could assign the values to the variables, but your response fixed it all! tysm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presented code does not make a sense nevertheless answering your question

> how do I assign a value to a struct array inside a struct in c?

I will explain how you can do this.

If you have an object declared like

```
t_baraja b1;
```

then to set data members of its data member array

```
 t_carta cartas[DIM];
```

you can the following way

```
b1.cartas[i].palo; = some_value;
b1.cartas[i]valor = another_value;.
```

where `i` is an index that selects an element in the data member array `cartas`.

Comment: thanks! I know it didn't make sense so that's why i was asking anyway